# How can I use jQuery to determine if an object is a select?

Tags: jquery

I have been using this to determine if an object is a "text" or not so I can get the .val or the checked state:

```
var val = object.is(":text") ? object.val() : object.is(":checked")
```

This works BUT now the object might also be:

1. From a select
2. From an input field
3. From a checkbox

Is there another way I could code this so it would also work for a select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to switch the logic around and take the `.val()` if the object is not a checkbox.

```
var val = object.is(":checkbox") ? object.is(":checked") : object.val();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I guess it doesn't like the "checkbox" selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var val = (object.is(":text") || object.is("select") )
    ? object.val() : object.is(":checked")
```